# Getting the parent from the matched element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got a doubt:

Is this a good practice to find a parent which it's two levels above the matched element.
The html structure looks like this:

```
<div class="cli_visitas left cli_bar hand" title="Control de las visitas del cliente">              
    <a href="/fidelizacion/visitas/nueva/id/<?php echo $cliente->getId();?>">
        <span id="cli_visitas<?php echo $cliente->getId();?>" class="cli_bar_msg">La última visita <span class="lastvisit" ><?php echo $this->estados()->getUltimaVisita($cliente->getId());?></span></span>
   </a>
</div>
```

'.lastvisit' fire the event, and I want to get the parent '.cli_visitas' div 
I'm doing this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().css({boxShadow : '0px 0px 5px #DF0101',backgroundColor:'#F89494'});
```

Is this a good practice? I don't want to use .parents() method and iterate over each element and find the parent I'd like access it directly.
I have tried with .get() but I think this method is not good for my propouse
Is there another way to do it?

Thank you very much.
Greetings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using below two alternatives.

**One**

```
$(this).closest('div.cli_visitas')
```

**Second**

```
$(this).parents('div.cli_visitas')
$(this).parents('div.cli_visitas').eq(1)
```

**Cool Explanation added in comment by Franc**

> As an additional note, for OP's benefit, on how those differ `.closest()` will get the first element that matches the selector traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree. It will stop as soon as it found a match `.parents()` on the other hand will get all ancestors matching the specified selector, or all parent ancestors if no selector was specified. Therefore if you have a very large nested DOM tree, `closest()` will be more efficient. Off course, if you need to access the nth-ancestor in the match `parents().eq()` would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: +1 for alternatives. As an additional note, for OP's benefit, on how those differ. `closest()` will get the first element that matches the selector traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree. It will stop as soon as it found a match. `parents()` on the other hand will get all ancestors matching the specified selector, or all parent ancestors if no selector was specified. Therefore if you have a very large nested DOM tree, `closest()` will be more efficient. Off course, if you need to access the nth-ancestor in the match `parents().eq()` would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: What @FrançoisWahl said. Including .parents() is probably your downfall.

Comment: See perf difference between closest/parents: http://jsperf.com/jquery-parents-vs-closest/31  Closest is better even in old jquery parents was better

Comment: @SOliver well i forget too explain about both performance that does not mean down vote dude...  and francois wahl +1 for good explanation...i will add that in answer.

Comment: @DipeshParmar I'd go further to say that order of precedence would be assumed by the reader as .parents() then .closest().

Comment: @SOliver so you want me to give first position for closest and second for parents...if yes then i have already edited it.

Comment: @DipeshParmar Personally I'd suggest removing .parents() altogether, we have no idea of the elements outwith the demonstrated html; there may very well be another parent instance of `div.cli_visitas` further up the DOM.7

Comment: @SOliver what about having `parents('div.cli_visitas').eq(1)`..?

Comment: @DipeshParmar That'd do the job, although it's less elegant (now having an additional call appended) and it's still going to climb the entire DOM before returning a result. It's just not that good a method for the task at hand (.parents()) that is.

Answer (score 2):

How about using:

```
 $(this).closest('.cli_visitas').css(...
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you want to use [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)? You can do this chaining with the [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$(this).parents().eq(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [jQuery.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method instead. This will allow you to get not just the immediate parent but the ancestors beyond that within the DOM tree.

```
$(this).parents('DIV.cli_visitas').css({boxShadow : '0px 0px 5px #DF0101',backgroundColor:'#F89494'});
```